# Inconsistent summary results for geeglm model

Tags: r

I am using geeglm models for a study and the first time I run summary() of my model, I get output with 4 significant figures after the decimal place. The second, and all subsequent times, that I run the EXACT SAME code, the numbers are rounded to only 3 significant figures after the decimal place, which changes my p-value. If I restart my R Studio session, I get the 4 sig fig version again once and then the 3 sig fig version thereafter. Why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
age_mod <- geeglm(study_role ~ age_days, id = as.factor(correct_hospitalid), data = cryp, family = binomial, corstr = "exchangeable")
print(summary(age_mod), digits=4)
summary(age_mod)
```

Output the first time I run it:

```
> summary(age_mod1)

Call:
geeglm(formula = study_role ~ age_days, family = binomial, data = cryp, 
    id = as.factor(correct_hospitalid), corstr = "exchangeable")

 Coefficients:
              Estimate    Std.err  Wald Pr(>|W|)    
(Intercept) -1.5666759  0.2182308 51.54 7.02e-13 ***
age_days     0.0002135  0.0002516  0.72    0.396    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation structure = exchangeable 
Estimated Scale Parameters:

            Estimate Std.err
(Intercept)   0.9915  0.1695
  Link = identity 

Estimated Correlation Parameters:
      Estimate Std.err
alpha -0.09795  0.1278
Number of clusters:   182  Maximum cluster size: 3
```

Output the second and subsequent times I run it:

```
> summary(age_mod1)

Call:
geeglm(formula = study_role ~ age_days, family = binomial, data = cryp, 
    id = as.factor(correct_hospitalid), corstr = "exchangeable")

 Coefficients:
             Estimate   Std.err  Wald Pr(>|W|)    
(Intercept) -1.566676  0.218231 51.54    7e-13 ***
age_days     0.000214  0.000252  0.72      0.4    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation structure = exchangeable 
Estimated Scale Parameters:

            Estimate Std.err
(Intercept)    0.991   0.169
  Link = identity 

Estimated Correlation Parameters:
      Estimate Std.err
alpha  -0.0979   0.128
Number of clusters:   182  Maximum cluster size: 3
```